# Decoding ble hci snoop logs in Android

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am debugging an android disconnection issue and have gathered bluetooth hci snoop logs and have browsed it via wireshark tool but i am not able to understand the datapackets being shown in the logs. Is there any official /non official documentation for understanding these hci snoop logs?

Answer (score 1):

It's the Bluetooth HCI protocol. You can download the manual at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications. Press "Core Version 5.0" to download the current version (5). If you check out Vol 2 Part E chapter 7, you will see all kind of packets. The ACL data packets depend on what kind of data it is (higher layer specification). For example GATT, you will find the documentation in Vol 3 Part G.